# Simple nested loop not pipelining on TI C64x+

Tags: c, nested-loops, texas-instruments, pipelining

The following code is not pipelining when compiled on the C64x+:

```
void main ()
{
    int a, b, ar[100] = {0};

    for (a = 0; a < 1000; a++)
        for (b = 0; b < 100; b++)
            ar[b]++;

    while(1);
}
```

My IDE (Code Composer v6) gives the following message for the inner loop: "Loop cannot be scheduled efficiently, as it contains complex conditional expression. Try to simplify condition."

The problem seems to be with the nested loop, but I can't find any more information about optimizing one as simple as this.

Has anyone solved a similar issue before?

-- Additional information --

- Processor: TMS320C64x+
- Compiler: TI v8.0.3
- *Compiler flags*:-mv6400+ --abi=eabi -O3 --opt_for_speed=4 --include_path="D:/TI/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-c6000_8.0.3/include" --advice:performance -g  --issue_remarks --verbose_diagnostics --diag_warning=225 --gen_func_subsections=on --debug_software_pipeline --gen_opt_info=2 --gen_profile_info -k --c_src_interlist --asm_listing --output_all_syms
- *Linker flags*: -mv6400+ --abi=eabi -O3 --opt_for_speed=4 --advice:performance -g --issue_remarks --verbose_diagnostics --diag_warning=225 --gen_func_subsections=on --debug_software_pipeline --gen_opt_info=2 --gen_profile_info -k --c_src_interlist --asm_listing --output_all_syms -z -m"dsp.map" -i"D:/TI/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-c6000_8.0.3/lib" -i"D:/TI/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-c6000_8.0.3/include" --reread_libs --warn_sections --xml_link_info="dsp_linkInfo.xml" --rom_model

Comment: is this information for the inner loop or the outer?

Comment: @user3528438 for the inner loop, just updated the question

Comment: For this example, can't you set each element in `ar` to 1000 and avoid the inner loop?

Comment: strange, with TI v6.1 I get `ii = 1  Schedule found with 7 iterations in parallel`

Comment: @Alejandro this is a test case for a more complex example. In this case, that would work, but the same loop scheduling message is given for the more complex case, where that would not

Comment: @user3528438 I'll downgrade and try it out. I'm getting this message for v7.4.12 as well

Comment: FYI I'm using `-mo --keep_asm -mv6400+ -o3`

Comment: @user3528438 Simila problem with those flags on v6.1.23. Don't get the inline advice, but the compiler feedback says "Disqualified loop: Loop contains control code"

Comment: is this the full code you are trying to compile? does the "control code" mentioned by the compilier(s) exist?

Comment: @user3528438 I've updated the question. Shown is the entire project code, along with the compiler and linker flags

Comment: Do you get the same warning if you use a pointer instead of array indexing?  `for (a = 0; a < 1000; a++) { int *ptr = ar;
        for (b = 0; b < 100; b++)
            {*ptr++; ptr++}}

Comment: @SteveKolokowsky That yields "Disqualified loop: Bad loop structure"

Comment: @user3528438 Could you list all the compiler flags you used?

Comment: The flags I've posted are all I used. I suggest not using "source interlist" flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `--gen_profile_info` from the compiler flags solved the issue. My loops have been splooped.